# Is it possible to put mdf and ldf to NAS (Synology)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm planning to purchase NAS (synology) for personal use. I'm working also as developer, it is possible to put my test database (SQL server data and log) to NAS? This just for personal and for development purpose. Because I have two pc setup on 1st floor and 2nd floor of our house, I just don't want to copy and paste the database every now and then when I go to my pc to another. Or do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, you can create an iSCSI device on your Synology NAS and use that as your storage location for SQL Server.

Comment: Why do you need to copy and paste the database? Can't it just be hosted using the SQL Server service on one PC or the other? When you go downstairs, you access it remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to store the files on the NAS.

A bigger problem will be moving between PCs. Each machine will be its own instance of SQL Server. It will not be possible for both instances to own the database files at the same time. You will have to attach the file to one instance, work on that machine, detach from that machine, go to the other and attach the files to that instance before you can work on the DB.

A simpler approach would would be to have one of your boxes (the more powerful one) own the files permanently. Use the other box to remotely communicate with the owning box. Use a remote desktop session, or simply have SSMS (or other client tool) resolve to the host\instance name.

Comment: I will take this approach.